# Django URL "contains" some string?

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

How to check if my URL contains some string?

`url(r'^search/.*callback.*$', 'event_search_jsonp', {}, 'event_search_jsonp'),`

Doesn't work! Django doesn't use event_search_jsonp view if I have callback in my url - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/search/?callback=123`

**EDIT 1**

I have something like this and how I can get `request` here?

```
class SearchView(APIView):
    if 'callback' in self.request.GET:
        renderer_classes = (JSONPRenderer, )
    else:
        renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )

    def get(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
        events = Event.objects.all().order_by("-id")[:10]
        serializer = EventSerializer(events, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django URLs don't include the querystring, which is the bit after the `?`. You'd need to do the test in your view:

```
def event_search_jsonp(request):
    if 'callback' in request.GET:
        # do_something
```

**Edit**

That doesn't work because class-level attributes are defined at import time, not at run time. Rather than doing the test there, you need to define the `get_renderers` method. Something like:

```
class SearchView(APIView):
    def get_renderers(self):
        if 'callback' in self.request.GET:
            return JSONPRenderer()
        else:
            return JSONRenderer()
```

Comment: I use CBV from Django REST Framework, and I don't have request object when I set renderrer.

Comment: Yes you do, the request is always available in a CBV as `self.request`.